# Manage Categories in Site part. Is possible?

Tags: joomla-3.x, category

I use the com_categories in my custom component based on the joomla Docs [Adding Categories](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_categories).

But I need to manage the categories in the site part. I was wondering if there is an easy way to do it, or do I have to create my own categories table and create my MVC without using core categories ?

Thank you

Comment: The Access Control Layer should allow you to grant permission to users to modify on the front end.  (I have no experience in this domain)  I certainly don't recommend designing a duplicate categories table -- you should use the core categories table.  Hopefully someone with experience/expertise can post an educational answer.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem is not the permissions but if I have to rewrite mvc again or I can do it as easy as described in the backend in the Docs. I wonder that because com_categories do not exist in the /components folder, so there is no frontend.